# Dealing with a worksheet name with spaces

Tags: vba, excel

I'm able to set a worksheet name without spaces and manipulate it with out issue. However, everything I've tried with spaces doesn't work.

```
Dim myBook As Workbook
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Set myBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set myWorksheet = myBook.Sheets("my worksheet name")
```

I've tried setting single quotes around it alone.

Comment: I recomment to use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. `ActiveWorkbook` is not explicit whereas `ThisWorkbook` is and always refers to the Workbook / Excel File containing the macro which is being executed.

Answer (score 2):

Try using sheet name between single quotes as follows:

```
Set myWorksheet = myBook.Sheets("'my worksheet name'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work fine, provided the workbook in question is the active workbook and has a worksheet named "my worksheet name" without any leading or trailing spaces.

Try examining the worksheet names as follows:

```
For Each myWorksheet In myBook.Sheets
    Debug.Print """" & myWorksheet.Name & """"
Next myWorksheet
```

This encloses the name in quotes so you can easily see if the name has leading or trailing spaces.